# Creating context in an independent project class

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using the following class to translate texts depending on the device's locale:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:yaml/yaml.dart';

class MovMapLocalizations {
  final String localeName;
  MovMapLocalizations(this.localeName);

  static const LocalizationsDelegate<MovMapLocalizations> delegate =
      _MovMapLocalizationsDelegate();

  YamlMap translations;
  Future load() async {
    String yamlString = await rootBundle.loadString('lang/${localeName}.yml');
    translations = loadYaml(yamlString);
  }

  String t(String key) {
    try {
      var keys = key.split(".");
      dynamic translated = translations;
      keys.forEach((k) => translated = translated[k]);
      if (translated == null) {
        return "Key not found: $key";
      }
      return translated;
    } catch (e) {
      return "Key not found: $key";
    }
  }
}

class _MovMapLocalizationsDelegate
    extends LocalizationsDelegate<MovMapLocalizations> {
  const _MovMapLocalizationsDelegate();
  @override
  bool isSupported(Locale locale) {
    print("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@LOCALE ACTUAL:"+locale.languageCode);
    return ['es', 'en'].contains(locale.languageCode);
  }

  @override
  Future<MovMapLocalizations> load(Locale locale) async {
    var t = MovMapLocalizations(locale.languageCode);
    await t.load();
    return t;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReload(covariant LocalizationsDelegate<MovMapLocalizations> old) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

I have also two yaml files to declare the translations: en.yaml and es.yaml:

en.yaml

```
login:
  email: Email
  password: Password
  login: Sign In
  signup: Sign Up
  or: Or
  newHere: New Here?

signup:
  email2: Email
  password2: Password
  login2: Sign In
  signup2: Sign Up
  or2: Or
  alreadyAccount: Already Have an User Account?

muro:
  expand: read more
  collapse: close
  delete: Delete
  denunciar: Report
  already: Has already been reported
  has_denunciado: You have reported this post

time_ago:
  yearsago: years ago
```

es.yaml

```
login:
  email: Correo electrónico
  password: Contraseña
  login: Entrar
  signup: Registrar
  or: O
  newHere: ¿Nuevo aquí?

    signup:
      email2: Correo electrónico
      password2: Contraseña
      login2: Entrar
      signup2: Registrar
      or2: O
      alreadyAccount: ¿Ya tienes cuenta de usuario?
    
    muro:
      expand: leer más
      collapse: cerrar
      delete: Borrar
      denunciar: Denunciar
      already: Ya ha sido denunciado
      has_denunciado: Has denunciado este post
    
    time_ago:
      yearsago: años
```

Then on every class where I need to make use of translations I am including:

```
MovMapLocalizations localizations =
    Localizations.of<MovMapLocalizations>(context, MovMapLocalizations);
```

And later, to translate a given text I put the related translation as:

```
Text(localizations.t("muro.denunciar")
```

But now I need to implement the use of translations inside a separate class called which doesn't have a context to make use of:

```
MovMapLocalizations localizations =
        Localizations.of<MovMapLocalizations>(context, MovMapLocalizations);
```

This is the class:

```
class TimeAgo{

  String formatearFecha(Timestamp timestamp){
    var dateFromTimeStamp =
        DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(timestamp.seconds * 1000);
    return DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm').format(dateFromTimeStamp);
  }
   String timeAgoSinceDate(String dateString, {bool numericDates = true}) {
    DateTime date = DateTime.parse(dateString);
    final date2 = DateTime.now();
    final difference = date2.difference(date);

    if ((difference.inDays / 365).floor() >= 2) {
      return '${(difference.inDays / 365).floor()} years ago';
    } else if ((difference.inDays / 365).floor() >= 1) {
      return (numericDates) ? '1 year ago' : 'Last year';
    } else if ((difference.inDays / 30).floor() >= 2) {
      return '${(difference.inDays / 365).floor()} months ago';
    } else if ((difference.inDays / 30).floor() >= 1) {
      return (numericDates) ? '1 month ago' : 'Last month';
    } else if ((difference.inDays / 7).floor() >= 2) {
      return '${(difference.inDays / 7).floor()} weeks ago';
    } else if ((difference.inDays / 7).floor() >= 1) {
      return (numericDates) ? '1 week ago' : 'Last week';
    } else if (difference.inDays >= 2) {
      return '${difference.inDays} days ago';
    } else if (difference.inDays >= 1) {
      return (numericDates) ? '1 day ago' : 'Yesterday';
    } else if (difference.inHours >= 2) {
      return '${difference.inHours} hours ago';
    } else if (difference.inHours >= 1) {
      return (numericDates) ? '1 hour ago' : 'An hour ago';
    } else if (difference.inMinutes >= 2) {
      return '${difference.inMinutes} minutes ago';
    } else if (difference.inMinutes >= 1) {
      return (numericDates) ? '1 minute ago' : 'A minute ago';
    } else if (difference.inSeconds >= 3) {
      return '${difference.inSeconds} seconds ago';
    } else {
      return 'Just now';
    }
  }

}
```

What should I do to make it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a top-level `GlobalKey` to `MaterialApp`'s `navigatorKey` property.
Then you can get the current route's context by `globalKey.currentContext`.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/navigatorKey.html